# I have to go back to my first router from nth router in flutter using GoRouter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-go-router

I have sequence of routing like A->B->C->D, now i am in my fourth router, its a kind of success page after an api call, now when I tap on done button on route D it should bring user back to my first router A also it should clear all B,C,D. is there anyway in achieving this using GoRouter package in flutter, thanks in advance.

Comment: This depends on how you defined the route. If you define every next step as a child route of the previous step, such as B is the child route of A and C is the child route of B, then you just need to do `context.go('/a')`

Comment: all my routers are a separate screens, there is no parent child relationship. can this still be achievable here(am currently poping screen one by one until reaching A, i dont think that is right option.

Comment: Are you using `context.go` or `context.push`?